# Gnome Tab not recognizing Rails anymore using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, ruby

I am having a strange issue , my main terminal is recognizing the RVM , Ruby and runs Rails command as well , and I had two tabs opened yesterday which were recognizing all of the commands .

Today morning when I opened my terminal and tab ,

terminal recognizes everything , but tab only recognizes RVM and ruby, but not rails and throws out this error .

error - The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install

I have ticked the box run command as login shell in the preferences , but of no use .

update:- I tried running rvm use ruby-2.2.0@learn in the tab (The main terminal window doesnt require this being run ) and it throws this error -

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.0'.
```

Using /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0 with gemset learn

Any suggestions or help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you installed rvm in multiusermode you should check that the following code is in your bashrc.

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```